# JSON data not returning

Tags: android, android-json

I have written a code to access the below api and get the corresponding values of namaz timings, but the onResponse method is not getting invoked. I have given internet permissions in the android manifest file. I am new to Android, please help.

While Installing app is not asking for internet permissions though I mentioned it in manifest file.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class NamazTiming extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView fazarId, zoharid, asarid, magribid, ishaid, location;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.namaz_timing);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Namaz Timings");

        fazarId = findViewById(R.id.fazarid);
        zoharid = findViewById(R.id.zoharid);
        asarid = findViewById(R.id.asarid);
        magribid = findViewById(R.id.magribid);
        ishaid = findViewById(R.id.ishaid);
        location = findViewById(R.id.location);

        Button locationbutton = findViewById(R.id.locationbutton);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        locationbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jsonParse();
            }
        });
    }

    private void jsonParse() {
        //String loc = location.getText().toString().trim();
        String url ="https://muslimsalat.com/uravakonda.json?key=ba8d0b5ba55c6db3cebbe3fefd6090f8";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Toast.makeText(NamazTiming.this, "Entered onresponse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                Toast.makeText(NamazTiming.this, "Entered into TRY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String Fazar = response.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).get("fajr").toString();
                String Zohr = response.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).get("dhuhr").toString();
                String Asar = response.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).get("asr").toString();
                String Magrib = response.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).get("maghrib").toString();
                String Isha = response.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).get("isha").toString();

                fazarId.setText(Fazar);
                zoharid.setText(Zohr);
                asarid.setText(Asar);
                magribid.setText(Magrib);
                ishaid.setText(Isha);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(NamazTiming.this, "Please enter the lccation name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(NamazTiming.this, "Please enter the lccation name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please share the log from android studio

Comment: did you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `request` object to the Volley queue (in your case, `mQueue`) in order for the request to be executed.

Example:
`mQueue.add(request);`

Answer (score 0):

Internet permission is normal permission so the android system will not ask internet permission.

You just call this line:

`mQueue.add(request);`

end of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line after errorListener method at end of your request

```
mQueue.add("your request type");
```